# RML (OpenERP) - dynamically group lines that meet a condition

Tags: python, xml, odoo, rml

Let say I have this table:

```
 <para style="terp_default_2">[[ repeatIn(o.invoice_line,'l') ]]</para>
      <blockTable colWidths="180.0,65.0,75.0,70.0,60.0,80.0" style="Table8">
        <tr>
          <td>
            <para style="terp_default_9">[[ format(l.name) ]]</para>
          </td>
          <td>
            <para style="terp_default_Centre_9">[[ formatLang(l.discount, dp='Account', digits=2) ]] </para>
          </td>
          <td>
            <para style="terp_default_Right_9">[[ formatLang(l.quantity, digits=2)]] [[ (l.uos_id and l.uos_id.name) or '' ]]</para>
          </td>
          <td>
            <para style="terp_default_Centre_9">[[ formatLang(l.price_unit, digits=2) ]]</para>
          </td>
          <td>
            <para style="terp_default_Centre_9">[[ ', '.join([ lt.name or '' for lt in l.invoice_line_tax_id ]) ]]</para>
          </td>          
          <td>
            <para style="terp_default_Right_9">[[ formatLang(l.price_subtotal, dp='Account', digits=2, currency_obj=o.currency_id) ]]</para>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </blockTable>
```

This table generates and prints invoice lines normally, but I need to group them in "groups" if they are assigned to that so-called "group".

What I mean is that if order line is assigned "Allotment Partner" (There is such field in Sales Orders, which I will add in invoice too), then they are added to that group. To understand it better lets take a look in this example:

Now with code written above, invoice would be printed something like this:

```
product1 discount1 quantity1 priceu1 taxes1 prices1
product2 discount2 quantity2 priceu2 taxes2 prices2
product3 discount3 quantity3 priceu3 taxes3 prices3
```

Now if those lines would be assigned that 'Allotment Partner', for example first and second line would be assigned `allot_p1` and third line would be assigned `allot_p2` (let say these are the names for Allotment Partners). So then it should print like this:

```
allot_p1
product1 discount1 quantity1 priceu1 taxes1 prices1
product2 discount2 quantity2 priceu2 taxes2 prices2
allot_p2
product3 discount3 quantity3 priceu3 taxes3 prices3
```

I imagine how to just show Allotment Partner for every line like this:

```
allot_p1 product1 discount1 quantity1 priceu1 taxes1 prices1

allot_p1 product2 discount2 quantity2 priceu2 taxes2 prices2

allot_p2 product3 discount3 quantity3 priceu3 taxes3 prices3
```

This one would be easy as I would just need to create additional `td`. But such approach would not look that good, so I think it is possible to somehow automatically group lines and print it like in second example?

Comment: you need to use queries and wizard report to achieve this

Comment: @senthilnathang can you write an example how to do that?

Comment: check accounting reports such as balance sheet